# Powershell Quotation Marks

Tags: sql-server, powershell, variables

So I have a script almost up but I'm having trouble inserting a variable with quotes.

Here is the code, look specifically at `$sqlresult`. I have it in single quotes so obviously it just enters the string `error[0]` as text, I'm looking to have it call the variable and that part of the index.

```
#error handle
if ($error)
    {
#Assemble the Query
    $sqlresult = '$error[0]'
    $sqlcontext = ($strfilename + ' ' + $content.length + ' bytes')
    $strquery = 
    "INSERT INTO [logs].[dbo].[EventLog] (SourceID, Started, Completed, Result, Context, Machine)
        values (50,'$starttime','$endtime','$sqlresult','$sqlcontext','1sl-den-db03-CAFEEDSCRIPT')"
#Create Command and Execute.
    $sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = $strQuery
    $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Double quotes makes the script return

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near 'calling'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a 
semicolon."
At line:40 char:5
+     $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Which I've basically learned is "yo, your sql statement is eff'd up!"

My guess is I have to do something in the query itself with the sqlresult variable? I'm not sure.

Comment: Remove the single quotes from all the variables in your `INSERT` statement and try. Instead of `$strquery = "INSERT INTO [logs].[dbo].[EventLog] (SourceID, Started, Completed, Result, Context, Machine) values(50,'$starttime','$endtime','$sqlresult','$sqlcontext','1sl-den-db03-CAFEEDSCRIPT')"` try to do `$strquery = "INSERT INTO [logs].[dbo].[EventLog] (SourceID, Started, Completed, Result, Context, Machine) values(50,$starttime, $endtime, $sqlresult, $sqlcontext, '1sl-den-db03-CAFEEDSCRIPT')"`.

Comment: When you are building queries like this I find it helpful to simply `Write-Host $strquery` so that you can see exactly what the query looks like. Sometimes on tricky ones I will even take that query and paste it into a query in SQL Admin Studio to sort out what is wrong with the query syntax.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh These need single quotes around them for SQL purposes. Just like the last value is '1sl-den-db03-cafeedscript' with single quotes. I just tried what you suggested for posterity sake and it didn't work. (same error)

Comment: @EBGreen My write-hosts do exactly what I expect. WHen I write-host $error[0] I get the string I want. I just can't seem to get it into a variable and then drop it into the query.

Like I said, if I single quotes it so it's just a text string, it drops in just fine. 

so $sqlresult = 'error[0]'
Dropped into the query as ,'$sqlresult' writes the text string 'error[0] into the database just fine.

Comment: Do this: `Write-Host $strquery`. What does that output?

Comment: The SQL engine is never going to "call a powershell variable", how could it? What about changing `'$sqlresult'` to `'$($error[0])'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$Error[0]` will always have returns, provided its not empty, maybe what you are looking for is `$sqlresult = $Error[0].Exception.Message`

If you are handling this in a catch block you could do `$sqlresult = $_.Exception.Message`

Comment: Exception.Message is super useful.
Also! I figured out what I think is happening, just don't know how to fix. 

My sqlresult writes as 
Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file '\\1sl-den-db04\d$\Data\feeds\CA\1stoplighting1.txt'."

And those quotes are being directly inserted into the query and the query is FREAKING out because of that ending string
'." and then I add a ' to it. So the string for that value in the query ends with 
'."' and sql doesn't like it. 

Thoughts?